# Rolling Upgrade of Oracle 11g from 32 bit to 64 bit?

Tags: oracle, 64-bit, oracle-11g, 32-bit

I have an Oracle 11.1.0.7 database running on windows 32 bit.  I would like to upgrade to 64 bit (same version of oracle) and would like to use a standby database for a rolling upgrade.  Is this possible and can I make the standby the primary so I don't have to have another outage to roll back to the primary?

Comment: Is this a RAC installation?

Comment: No, we are not using RAC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You will need to used logical standby which can be a bit trickier than physical. However, you can't have a physical standby with a different architecture than the primary.
2. Yes, you can make the standby primary. It is called role switchover:
   http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14239/role_management.htm#i1026400

Comment: +1 Thanks for the great answer and the documentation link.  I was thinking I would need a logical standby during the upgrade, but I was hoping I could start out with a physical and convert to logical just before the upgrade.  I think you are saying that 32 bit and 64 bit are different architectures, so I can't create the physical standby at all.  Is that correct?  If it is that means I'll have to deal with the statements that don't transfer in a logical standby for a longer period of time.

Comment: I never actually tried, but as far as I know 32 bit and 64 bit are different architectures and require logical standby only.